# Enviar .pdf, em base64, por e-mail

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, pdf, envio-de-email, base64

Eu recebo uma string através de uma `API` externa, que vem direto do cliente (só cuido do website, tornando impossível alterar o tipo de informação que recebo). Essa string é um `.pdf` que foi encriptado em `base64` e eu preciso enviar ele em e-mail para o cliente, quando ele solicita, sendo que deve ser enviado o link do `.pdf`, e não o arquivo anexado.

Só para constar, trabalho com `PHP`, usando `Laravel`.

1. Se eu tento dar decode nessa string, ele gera um stream gigante, mas como eu faria para gerar o link com esse stream?
2. Se eu utilizo o comando `window.open("data:application/pdf," + codigo_base64);` no `Javascript`, consigo abrir o `.pdf` perfeitamente em outra aba do navegador, mas, como eu disse, preciso enviar o mesmo por e-mail, assim, perdendo qualquer funcionalidade de usar `Javascript`. Ou estou incorreto?
3. Se eu tento utilizar `<a href='data:application/pdf," + codigo_base64)'>`, o cliente de e-mail simplesmente ignora a existência do link, alguns cliente sequer exibem o link. (*e para falar a verdade, nem sei se tal comando é possível*)

Existe algum conseguir enviar esse `.pdf` por e-mail?

*Edição:* **Infelizmente, o cliente quer que seja enviado o link para download, e não o arquivo em anexo.**

Comment: Se você transformar novamente em `pdf` arquivo guarda em um pasta temporaria, faz um e-mail anexa esse item e enviar depois apaga o tempo? que tal ?

Comment: Qual é a versão do seu Laravel?

Comment: O problema é que meu cliente quer que seja enviado o link para download, e não o arquivo em anexo (esqueci de mencionar isso). Atualmente estou usando a versão 5.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para enviar um e-mail com anexo, onde o `.pdf` esteja em formato `base64` é fácil, precisa ***reverter*** esse `base64` para um ***arquivo fisico***, gravar em uma *pasta temporária* e enviar normalmente via anexo com a *classe* [Mail](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/mail) do [laravel](/questions/tagged/laravel)

Eu estou fazendo como se você já tivesse recebendo o dado dessa `API`:

```
Route::get('emailpdf', function()
{
    $data = "_dados_da_string_base64_arquivo_tipo_pdf";

    //gerando um nome para o arquivo
    $pathToFile = 'temp/'.uniqid().'.pdf';

    //salvar a string em uma pasta temporária para servir de anexo
    //com extensão e tipo PDF    
    file_put_contents($pathToFile, base64_decode($data));        

    //classe que envia o email  
    \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail::send('email', [], 
    function($message) use ($pathToFile)
    {
        $message->to('email_enviar@gmail.com');
        //anexando o arquivo criado na pasta temporária     
        $message->attach($pathToFile);

    });

    //excluindo o arquivo da pasta temporária
    unlink($pathToFile);

    return "Email enviado com sucesso";

});
```

Fico no aguardo de alguma mensagem do usuário para melhorar mais a **resposta**!

---

***Edição:***

Cliente deseja que seja enviado um link:

No template `email` coloque algo assim, utilize no template o `helper` [**asset**](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/helpers#urls):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Laravel</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="flex-center position-ref full-height">
    <h3>Email enviado com sucesso</h3>
    <p>
        <a href="{{asset($link_pdf)}}">PDF Link</a>
    </p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

e no código faça essas alterações, enviando para `View` o link criado e como esse arquivo não pode ser excluido removi a última linha:

```
Route::get('emailpdf', function()
{
    $data = "_dados_da_string_base64_arquivo_tipo_pdf";

    //gerando um nome para o arquivo
    $pathToFile = 'temp/'.uniqid().'.pdf';

    //salvar a string em uma pasta temporária para servir de anexo
    //com extensão e tipo PDF    
    file_put_contents($pathToFile, base64_decode($data));        

    //classe que envia o email  
    \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail::send('email',['link_pdf' => $pathToFile], 
    function($message) use ($pathToFile)
    {
        $message->to('email_enviar@gmail.com');
        //anexando o arquivo criado na pasta temporária     
        $message->attach($pathToFile);

    });

    return "Email enviado com sucesso";

});
```

Nesse caso envia o anexo e um link para o site, não recomendaria o link, mas, relatado por você coisa de cliente.

Comment: Não é exatamente o que eu preciso (pois o cliente quer um link, e não um anexo), mas a função funciona perfeitamente para disparar um anexo via e-mail. No pior dos casos, tentarei convencer de enviar o anexo!

Comment: @lmartim mas, mesmo assim está fácil de solucionar também com um link vou fazer a edição e colocar com link também.

Comment: Aí tu conseguiu resolver meu problema, eu não tinha o conhecimento dessa biblioteca assets! Muito obrigado pela ajuda!